# Where can I buy double-edged razor blades, while traveling in China?

Tags: china, shopping, toiletries

I use a razor that takes with a double-edge blade to shave, as I find cartridge razors to be expensive, irritating and easy to clog, and I am too lazy to take care of a straight razor properly! I recently went to China, and discovered that I didn't pack a box of spare blades:

[image: Box of razor blades]

Thinking that these would be easy to find, I went out to the supermarket and tried to find some. However, all I could find in any supermarket or pharmacy (e.g. Watson's) were racks of the Gillette multi-blade razors. Asking for the flat blades was just met with a blank look and a wave towards the cartridge razors. I eventually bought one of them since I needed to shave and had the subsequent unsatisfying shave and rash.

Where can you get double-edge flat razor blades in China? Have Gillette moved in and made it an online-only thing now? Decent ones would be a plus, rather than some off-brand ones of dubious sharpness!

Comment: That's a very good blade you have pictured there, so sharp I switched to a competitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get these razor at almost any HARDWARE shop in China ( yes you read correctly ) - at least in the southern part which I know better.
It will be very challenging for you to ask for it , but It is enough if you will show them an example . They are called 双面刀片 or just 刀片 (  dāopiàn ) .

The only problem is that some hardware shops will have different sizes and shapes that might not be suitable for you .

Another place they sell these are small local stationary shops ( office supply )
I also saw them in a lot of supermarkets and small groceries stores

That said - The foreign brands are not cheap in china , And I am not sure one should trust one's  face with the cheap Chinese ones.

You can find them easily online ( [example](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.57.Hj3jCe&id=12571005168&ns=1&abbucket=1#detail) , [example](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=528925952631&ali_refid=a3_430585_1006:1109391685:N:%E5%88%80%E7%89%87:86e6ce7448656f61fccc2bce13b086fe&ali_trackid=1_86e6ce7448656f61fccc2bce13b086fe&spm=a230r.1.14.1.Hj3jCe#detail) )

If you would say WHERE in China you need them, maybe I can help more ( China as a location is pretty big )

By the way, when I first arrived to China, NO FORM of razors nor shaving cream was available, and the only place to get it was online, or Abroad ... 
This is still a problem in rural areas in China, because the Chinese are known for lack of facial hair - but strangely enough - those double sided razors were available . 
Watsons and similar big brand shops will probably not have these because they hold only large-volume products. But if you will go to some small street with small old fashioned grocery shops- you WILL find them.

In Hong Kong and Macau those razors are available almost everywhere .

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I'm in north China (Tianjin), but I'll check out the hardware shops when I next run out of supplies!

Answer (score 2):

According to this [forum post](http://badgerandblade.com/vb/showthread.php/173616-Blades-Available-in-Hong-Kong) this is indeed very challenging but at least in Hong Kong

> Fanda pharmacy in Central (G/F Worldwide House - Central MTR)

seems to sell them. Checking other similar forums it seems your best bet is online.